# How do I get smooth scrolling on Mac Book Pro running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro

I have a 13" MBP purchased recently setup on a dual boot configuration of OSX/Win7.  Smooth scrolling works when booted into the OSX partition, but not when booted into the windows partition.  I am specifically hoping to get this working with the trackpad.  Know of any drivers I can download?  or any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "unified" smooth scrolling feature across operating systems. "Smooth scrolling" works in a browser and depends on proper "VGA-device" drivers. If you have an Nvidia card head over to their support site and get the all-in-one driver package, if you have something else just google the name of the graphics card and append "download driver" in the search query.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try "Smooth Scroll" extensions in Google Chrome/MS Edge browser. It provides smooth-scrolling things in windows 10 like in macOs
2. Same as above, goto "www.smoothscroll.net" and try their app, which makes apps such as ms word scrolling smoothly on windows 10 like on macOS. However, one should pay for it.

I'm still trying to find an open source app which can provide similar functionality on windows 10.